# Can event triggers be used to alter the owner of a newly created table to a role the creator is not a member of?

Tags: postgresql

I want to alter the owner of a postgreSQL table upon creation. So far so good.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_create_set_table_owner()
 RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  obj record;
BEGIN
  FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() WHERE command_tag='CREATE TABLE' LOOP
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s OWNER TO blubb', obj.object_identity);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

However, I would like to change the owner to a role that the user creating the table is not a part of. Is that possible at all?

Comment: if you add a function with SU that will acpect tbalename and rolename as arguments with security definer - yes

Comment: I guess I should have RTFM. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: well - `security definer`  is an easy part. the harder one - to make the function "safe" for not meant use

Comment: also not much related, but `%s` isn't the best choice for identifier

Comment: Care to elaborate? We want all newly created tables to have the same owner. Do you see a security risk there?

Comment: I did in my answer I believe :)

Comment: I am a bit slow I guess. The role name is fixed, not parameterized. What is the worst thing that could happen in this scenario? Someone changes the owner of an existing table to that role? Since we want all user created tables in the database to share the same owner, is that still a problem?

Comment: changing not expected tables owner to blubb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SECURITY DEFINER

> Because a SECURITY DEFINER function is executed with the privileges of
>   the user that owns it, care is needed to ensure that the function
>   cannot be misused

Apart of this - just create a function with SU that will accept tablename and rolename as arguments and will run `ALTER TABLE`. grant execute to the role, consuming `trg_create_set_table_owner` and it will work. But the concern that the role can use the ability to alter table outside of `trg_create_set_table_owner` remains...

Of course you can check the possible role names and table names from a list of allowed before passing them to `execute format('ALTER TABLE %I OWNER TO %I')`